# Нужно чтобы в значении выводилось цифра после N, а в ключе цифры после V

Tags: c#

Нужно чтобы в значении выводилось цифра после N, а в ключе цифры после V. Что не так? в значении выводится B, а не 0

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "N0B3W300V150N0B3W300V400N0B3W300V650N0B3W300V850N2B1W600V2500N0B3W300V2150N0B3W300V2400N0B3W300V2650N0B3W300V2850N0B3W300V4150N0B3W300V4400N0B3W300V4650N0B3W300V4850";
        string[] words = SplitText(input);
        Dictionary<string, char> resultDict = CreateDictionary(words);
        PrintDictionary(resultDict);
    }
   
    static string[] SplitText(string text)
    {
       
        string[] words = text.Split(new string[] { "V", "N" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        return words;
    }
    
    static Dictionary<string, char> CreateDictionary(string[] words)
    {
        Dictionary<string, char> coordinatesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, char>();
        for (int i = 1; i < words.Length; i += 2)
        {
            string coordinate = words[i].Substring(0);
            char value = words[i - 1][1];
            coordinatesDictionary[coordinate] = value;
        }
        return coordinatesDictionary;
    }

    static void PrintDictionary(Dictionary<string, char> dictionary)
    {
        foreach (var entry in dictionary)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Ключ: {entry.Key}, Значение: {entry.Value}");
        }
    Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Это задание, которое нужно сделать, ок. А в чём у вас вопрос?

Comment: В том, что у меня не так? Потому что выводится ключ правильно, а в значении выводится B, то есть буква после N, а не цифра. N0B3W300V150 - если взять только эту строку, то должно вывести Ключ: 150, Значение: 0

Comment: Вы проверяли, что лежит в words? И почему в CreateDictionary извлекается char?

Comment: Не проще регуляркой сделать?

Comment: `var result = input.Split(new[] {'N', 'B', 'W', 'V'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Chunk(4).ToDictionary(key => key[3], value => value[0]);`

Comment: Что касается вашего кода, то вы не разбиваете по всем нужным значениям. Вот у вас строка `N0B3W300V150`, вы разбиваете по `V`, получаете `["N0B3W300", "150"]`, дальше разбиваете по `N` получаете `[ "", "0B3W300", "150"  ]`, так как стоит `RemoveEmptyEntries`, пустое значение убирается и на выходе у вас массив `["0B3W300", "150"]`. Собственно, разбивайте всю строку, по всем возможным символам, а уже потом берите нужное.

Comment: `words[i - 1][1]` - берётся символ по индексу 1, а нужно 0: `words[i - 1][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Решение на основе регулярки:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var result = Regex.Matches(input, @"N(\d+).+?V(\d+)(?=N|$)")
                  .ToDictionary(m => m.Groups[2].Value, m => m.Groups[1].Value);
```